# Writing a CV/resume: "from", "since, or "as of" 2010

Tags: word-choice

If I have been a member of the Committee from 2000, and its president as of 2010, would you write in a CV:

> Employer: XYZ (2000 - present)
>
> Position: President (**from/since/as of** 2010) of the Committee

Comment: Personally, I'd put, **President (2010-Present)** or **N Committee President (2010-Present)** so it'd have similar format to the line above: **XYZ (2000-Present)**.

Comment: In your example, use "since" as this one best indicates you are still the President.

Answer (score 1):

> Employer XYZ (2000 - present)
>   Position: Committee Member (2000 - 2010)
>   Position: Committee President (2010 - present)

or

> Employer XYZ (2000 - present)
>   Position: Member of the Committee (2000 - 2010)
>   Position: President of the Committee (2010 - present)